# Posting from an console application and a web app

Tags: c#, http-post

I have the same code in two systems, a console application and a website.  When the application posts the information, the webservice accepts the request.  When the website posts the information, the webservice shuts down the request.

It posts to exactly the same address.  I am not looking to rewrite it.

I want to know if there's any security settings thats preventing the service and site from talking to one another.  I don't think there's any point in showing the code because its the same in both systems.

The Errors I receive :-

Outer Error :-

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.'

Inner Errors :-

IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

It used to work perfectly so I am assuming it is a network configuration setting that someone has turned on say in the Firewall.

I've tried Fiddler which is able to see the console message but not the website message.

Comment: What do you mean by `shuts down the request`? Can you share the code? Are you getting any error from the web service?

Answer (score 0):

I can smell cross origin error. Can you hit F12 in your browser and see what it says in the console? If cross origin is the case (and I think it is) you need to enable cross origin requests in your backend. There are a lot of tutorial how to do it. The reason why cross origin is probably the case here is because console app is not a browser and the request will succeed. But when you are sending requests from browser, you backend app is looking if the request is comming from the same origin or not, and by default if it is not, it will tjrow you that error.